# Life would be easier if the Blender version was always visible in the interface so one can always know which version to use for tutorials

Tags: modeling

This is probably the wrong place to submit this but anyway.
Sometimes the author of a tutorial mentions the version he used but very often they do not. I have been frustrated beyond imagination by this issue. It already says "Blender" top left corner of interface would it be possible to add the version number to this as well so one can know at a glance what version was used for a given tutorial?
Thanks and apologies if this is the wrong place for this post.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For suggestions and feature requests use https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect or https://blenderartists.org. Before doing so consider that ideas are a dime-a-dozen, what we lack is manpower. Every single one of the millions of users have their own long list of personal wishes and desires, while comparatively very few people have the skills and knowledge to actually implement them.

Comment: Agreed and I am a dumb ass at least part time anyway. Thank you for your thoughtful reply.

Answer (score 2):

The version number is displayed in the bottom right corner:

[image: Version]

Comment: Unfortunately some tutorials have the tutor's image in that corner blocking out the version. - Not Blender's fault, I grant you!

Comment: Ok, thank you! The blind idiot will now humbly slink away never to complain again and go back over all those frustrating tutorials with renewed enthusiasm.